# Is there a modification to make the dot command work intuitively in visual mode?

Tags: visual-mode, repeated-commands

This is a repeat of a question that I asked on the Vim subreddit but didn't receive a helpful answer for. I think that this should be do-able, but I'm not good enough at Vimscript or Lua yet to implement it.

consider this short snippet of text:

```
(short text)
(long text long text long text)
```

With the cursor starting on the `t` of `short` entering the command `vi(U` capitalizes the text in the first parentheses. But then pressing `.` while in the second set of parentheses doesn't capitalize everything inside the parentheses, only a segment of text the same size of the content of the first parentheses. Is there a way to modify vim (or NeoVim) so that the dot command repeats the visual commands, and not just an operation on the same size of text?

Comment: You say "intuitive" but I'd argue that the visual selection size remaining the same when doing a repeat is more intuitive than any alternative! (And there are ways to accomplish what you want without Visual mode...which always seems less of "the Vim way", to me.)

Comment: `gUib` then `j.`

Comment: Of course I know that there are ways to accomplish this outside of visual mode. I'm asking this question to know if this method is generally possible, not for help with a specific task. For me the most intuitive behavior or the dot command would be for it to cause changes that are the same as if you had pressed the same key sequence that caused the last change.  So if the last command was visual mode, followed by motion/text object, and then operator, the dot command would operate on those motion ranges/text objects at the cursor's new position.

Comment: "Of course"? We don't know anything about you. We can't assume you know anything you don't specify. Anyways, what you're asking isn't possible without coding it all up and a general solution would likely be one heck of an undertaking...at least as far as an SE answer goes. (General FYI: the official word on this is under `:h .` where it says _when repeating a command that used a Visual selection, the same SIZE of area is used_ and this is repeated with additional details under `:h visual-repeat`.)

Comment: (cont.) My advice, if someone asked me for it, would be to basically avoid linewise and characterwise Visual mode. (Except for blockwise selections I _never_ use Visual mode.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to come off as condescending!

Comment: No worries. My response was just a justification for my and MaximKim's comments...not meant to be a scold.